# io.ReadAll error if adding a single character into a js script in html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, go

The problem:
i'm trying to create a messenger with golang. So, learning jQuery & AJAX for data updating without refreshing the page. I wrote a function to get data from textbox(js script sends POST to a golang server). Everything works ok until i add any js script in html file.

Golang function code:

```
func read_msgbox(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) string {
    var msg string
    defer r.Body.Close()
    body, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {

        log.Println("error catching submition", err)
        return ""
    }
    msg = string(body)

    return msg
}
```

Html + go templates file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Best messenger</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h2><a href="/">Messenger</a></h2>
            <h3>Chat with {{.Name}} </h3> 
            <p>Your message: 
                <form action="" name="msgboxform" id="msgboxform" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="msgbox" id="msgbox"> 
                </form>
                <script src="/static/JS/post_submit.js"></script>
            </p>
            </div>
            <link href="/static/CSS/message_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <p>
                Messages:
                <br>
                {{range .Msgs}}
                <div class = "box">
                    <div class = "text">
                        {{.Text}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-time">
                        <div class = "name">
                            {{.Sender_name}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="time">
                            {{.Time}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{end}}  
            </p>
        </main>
    </body>
    <script>
        function doSmth(){
        /*if i add smth there io.ReadAll errs "http: invalid Read on closed Body"
        unnecessary code, comment or spaces. Doesn't matter where in code the script is
        nothing happens if there are 3 spaces, but errs if i add 4th lmao */
        }
    </script>
    
</html>
```

post_submit.js:

```
const msgboxForm = document.getElementById("msgboxform")
msgboxForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let msg = new FormData(e.target).get("msgbox");
    document.getElementById("msgboxform").reset();
    $.ajax({
        url : window.location.href,
        type : 'POST',
        data : msg,
        connection : close,
        success : function(){
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Suppose this is because code somehow tries to read a request body before a response but idk what should i do with this.
I tried some staff with "Connection: close" in js AJAX submittion but looks like it doesn't solve the problem.

Also the message logs into a js console but there are something with go application that breaks.

Well, i found a solution - just change the url where js sends POST. Now there is a special url where every POST requests are handled.
Thx everyone!

And i'm sorry for spelling mistakes, english isn't my native language(my native is mostly c++) and also i hate spelling